# Create User Named Variables?

Tags: javascript, html

I would like to know whether is is possible to create variables that are named by the user when programming in javascript.

For example lets say i have a textbox and button to submit the value to a JS function that takes the value of the text inside the textbox. `var newvar = document.getElementById("mytxtbox").value;`

would it be possible to create a variable that would be called whatever the value of 'newvar' is?

I realize this is a very odd question but i thought this would be the best place to ask.

Thanks for all feedback,
Mike.

Comment: Why would you want to do that?

Answer (score 2):

You could do it with [`eval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Eval) but why would you want to? How would you know what your new variable is called outside the `eval`? A better way to do this sort of thing is to use an object as a runtime namespace of sorts:

```
var o = { };
var v = document.getElementById('some-text').value;
o[v]  = 'Where is pancake house?';

for(var p in o)
    console.log(p + ' was made at runtime and has a value of ' + o[p]);
```

Using an object as a namespace will probably let you do whatever it is you're trying to do without all the attendant risks of `eval`.

Answer (score 1):

This is possible via the eval function

```
var newVar = document.getElementById('mytxtbox').value;
eval(newVar + ' = 42');
```

This will cause a global variable of the name indicated by the text box value to be created.

I must ask though, what good is this for you?  It just opens a door for the user to trash any global state in your application

Answer (score 0):

It's easy to create a global variable with a particular name:

```
window[newVar]="This is a new variable";
```

It's harder to find a good reason for doing so.

I don't think there's a similarly trivial way to create a new local variable.

Answer (score 0):

yeap, using eval to create that variable. But you might need to use the eval whenever you need to use this variable.

```
var newVarName = document.getElementById("mytxtbox").value;

//declaration    
eval("var " + newVarName + " = " + newVarName);

//using it
eval("alert(" + newVarName + ")");
```

Well, I don't want to know why you need this, but if you mention, we might be able to find you a better solution than doing this :)